# Running code at the global scope in C++ (is there a more modern approach)?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run code at the global scope in C++.

I'm aware that it can be achieved using global variables (as their constructor is invoked before `main`). It's a very common pattern for libraries that need to collect "services" before running:

```
static int global_code = [] { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }();
```

For example, Google Test uses a similar technique for registering user defined unit-tests. In case you don't receive a unique-identifier from the user, you can use `__COUNTER__` to generate them (a non-standard extension which is available in most compilers).

My question: **Is anyone aware of a better way (maybe by (ab-)using new C++17 or c++2a features)?**

Edit:
By "better way" I mean anything you think would be an improvement of the above way, really. For example, a way that doesn't involve defining a global variable for each "registration" (global-code invocation).

Comment: How do you define "a better way"?

Comment: @FredLarson One that doesn't involve defining O(n) global variables.

Comment: Where `n` is what? You do realize you can put any number of lines of code in one lambda function, right?

Comment: You're right. What I meant is that for the service-registration use-case, one registration would involve one such global variable definition (for example, each `TEST` in Google Test introduces one global variable).

A good solution could have been one that reuses the same global variable. Though I don't know if it would be possible.